# Customising cakephp pagination to work with Solr query

Tags: cakephp, solr, pagination

I understand that cakephp pagination is tightly tied to sql querying. Is it possible to customised it to work with Solr query instead? I want the pagination to retrieve data from solr search instead of mysql query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a datasource for this DB. You should be able to use the regular CakePHP pagination methods if your model I using this datasource and if it was written correctly. <strike>There is https://github.com/ugrworks/cakephp-solr-webservice-datasource but its pretty old but I think you can re-use the code and work based on it.</strike>

**Update:** Now there is https://github.com/Highstrike/cakephp-solr-datasource for CakePHP 2.x

Comment: sorry but have you download the file and look through? There is nothing but folders.

Comment: That repository is no longer relevant, check my answer for my own implementatnion of a Solr DataSource

Comment: Thanks for the downvote for an answer that was correct at the time (~2.5 years ago) it was given. Not the polite kind of pushing your own answer.

Comment: removed my downvote now that you've updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've integrated Solr as a DataSource

https://github.com/Highstrike/cakephp-solr-datasource

You can also find there instructions on how to use it with examples. One of the example is the pagination you're looking for! Good luck.